# Transfer ownership of a Gmail account

Tags: gmail

I will be managing some social media accounts for someone for a while.  When I am finished, I want to be able to transfer the account to them. To keep it simple, I want to set up a Gmail account that I will use to establish the social media accounts.  Then when I am ready to transfer to them, I will just need to transfer ownership of the Gmail account to them, rather than all of the accounts.

What are the steps for transferring ownership of a Gmail account to another person?

Answer (score 3):

1. Make sure that that Gmail account is not being used for anything else, such as a login to stack exchange or as an account recovery option for some service.
2. Make sure the account isn't pulling in messages from some other POP, IMAP, or Gmail account.
3. Remove two factor from the account, that way the new person doesn't have to have access to your phone to login.
4. Change the password to something unrelated to your other accounts. I know that using the same password for multiple sites is bad, but many still do it.
5. Give the login credentials to the new account owner.
6. After they have been using the site for a week or so, remind them they should change the password, the recovery email, and a phone number for text messages/two factor.